# Mod Rewrite duplicating query

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am attempting to rewrite a page but I am getting a repeated query.

`http://www.website.com/settings/index.php?page=account`

Rewrites to this:

`http://www.website.com/settings/account`

So my issue is that when I use server validation on my page I redirect to `settings/account?valid=failed`but unfortunately I am getting:

`http://www.website.com/settings/account?valid=false&page=account`

This is my rewrite code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: What do you want it to look like?

Comment: Sorry should have added that. It should just be:
`http://www.website.com/settings/acount?valid=false`

Comment: Your problem is inside the PHP, not the htaccess.

Comment: So do you have a suggestion as to how I should construct the redirect url for the validation? I have tried `$SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."?valid=false"` and `htmlentities($SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).?valid=false` but still the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the php. The mod rewrite was not the problem.